# I have a table named records which has data column of jsonb type contains followin details. I am using postgres 9.5

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

```
{
  "propertyDetail": {
    "Plot NO": "11",
    "Society Name": "Trinity"
  },
  "personalDetail": {
    "Name": "Allen",
    "Location": "Mumbai",
    "emal": "abc@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

I want to update Location to address. like below

```
{
  "propertyDetail": {
    "Plot NO": "11",
    "Society Name": "Trinity"
  },
  "personalDetail": {
    "Name": "Allen",
    "Address": "Mumbai",
    "emal": "abc@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm migrating an old database either I have to update Location to location or Address. As the logic for front-end is all developed

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a better way than just adding the new one (with `jsonb_set`) and deleting the old one (with `#-`):

```
update thetable set x= 
    jsonb_set(x,'{personalDetail,Address}',x#>'{personalDetail,Location}')
    #-'{personalDetail,Location}'
```

Comment: I can't delete and add new as I am migrating data of more than 3 lakhs records. That's why I want to update.

Comment: There is no reason this can't be done with 3 lakh records.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I found the solution
UPDATE records SET data = replace(data::text, '"Location"', '"Address"')::jsonb;

Answer (score 0):

'''
UPDATE records SET data = replace(data::text, '"Location"', '"Address"')::jsonb;
'''

Comment: That is going to mess up if `"Location"`ever shows up in some other context, like as a value rather than a key.